# A book, about a boy who was a thief become goddess gifted hero

Tags: story-identification, books

Now I don't remember all the details. Most of my memory of it is gone. However it has been 14 years. What I do remember is this.

Boy starts off alone and a thief goes through a lot of trials and ends up at a temple and is granted an older body and super human abilities.

Comment: As it sits this will probably be difficult to answer. Try to add any details ,like what year did you read/when was it published, cover art, language, anything really.

Comment: *Redemption of Althalus*, the Eddings? About all I really remember about it is the hero was a thief, there was a goddess, and it's about that old.

Answer (score 5):

Without a lot of confirming details, this is a stretch, but the best fit I recall for your details is *[The Redemption of Althalus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Redemption_of_Althalus)* by David and Leigh Eddings.  It was released in Summer 2000.  Here's a snip from the article:

> Its main character is Althalus, a professional thief enlisted by the Goddess Dweia to save the world from the desolations of her evil brother Daeva and his henchman Ghend.

A lot of it takes place in a temple of sorts that sits beyond existence, with the party using doors in spacetime to get to where they need to be:

> Ghend hires Althalus to travel to the "House at the End of the World" to steal a book. Although he suspects something is amiss, Althalus accepts the job and heads there. After several days of travel he finds the house and manages to stumble upon the book, only to realize that the House is occupied by a talking cat who has trapped him. After several days of being trapped he finally decides to listen to the cat and thus finds out several astonishing things. The book is called the Book of Deiwos, Deiwos being the God who created the world, and the cat (named Emerald or Emmy by Althalus) teaches him to read it. After two and a half thousand years, Emerald reveals to Althalus that the book can be used to accomplish feats of magic ...

And this is the US cover I'm most familiar with...

[image]