# Fantasy book where a sorceress drafts a thief into helping her save the world

Tags: story-identification, books

A thief attempts to steal something from a tower. A sorceress (who can turn into a cat) drafts him into helping her save the world. He is put to sleep for a couple hundred years. There is a gold cache under a hill that he uses for his party that he travels with.

I'm pulling stuff from the memory of a book I read over 22 years ago, not a recent book. It is a fantasy book. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How sure are you about the "over 22 years ago" part? The first part of your description resembles some of the early plot elements of *The Redemption of Althalus* by David and Leigh Eddings, but that was first published in July of 2000, according to Wikipedia -- so 19 years ago.

Comment: Thats the book. My memory is not what it used to be. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @Lorendiac One of you should turn that into an answer.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188418/a-book-about-a-boy-who-was-a-thief-become-goddess-gifted-hero

Answer (score 7):

Per Lorendiac's [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213512/fantasy-book-where-a-sorceress-drafts-a-thief-into-helping-her-save-the-world#comment583061_213512) above, this is *The Redemption of Althalus* by David and Leigh Eddings. From [goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/110692.The_Redemption_of_Althalus):

> Althalus is a young thief and occasional killer known for his skill
>   and incredible luck... Althalus discovers Dweia in the form of a black
>   cat and learns that she has chosen him to aid her in a war against
>   Ghend and her evil brother, the destroyer god Daeva.